# How can I remove dropdown actionbutton overflow?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to remove the dropdown menu ActionButton Overflow, from Action Bar. In the case, it would be the one that has 3 points and default option "Settings".I would like to remove this item "Settings", so that, by clicking on the menu icon, he has to take action automatically. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "by clicking on the menu icon, he has to take action automatically"?

Comment: I mean, instead of show the dropdown with the items, he just execute the action, that can be, for example, an intent to another activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to folder menu->main then remove item settings then you can add another item (for example)

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh">
    </item>
```

and in your activity:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) // write your switch case to handle the clicked item.
```

the line that allows the option to be directly on the action bar is:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was doing  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" and it wasn't working. With android:showAsAction="ifRoom", works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the overflow. You can ask for the action bar to consider making one (or more) of your action bar items be toolbar-style buttons in the action bar. To do that:

- if you are using the native action bar, add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to the `<item>` in your menu resource
- if you are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, add `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to the `<item>` in your menu resource (assuming that you have the `appcompat-v7` namespace set to be `app`)

However, the decision on whether or not to show the item as a toolbar button or to put it in the overflow is up to the action bar, not you. For example, if you ask for 8 items to all be toolbar buttons, while that may be possible on a 10" tablet in landscape, there will not be enough room for all of them on a phone-sized screen in portrait. Some of your items will be toolbar buttons; the rest will go into the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all methods that create the menu (`onCreateOptionsMenu` etc).

Then in the XML file for the Toolbar, you have to add in the toolbar a custom icon. For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <----YOUR CUSTOM ICON/BUTTON HERE---->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then programmatically you can add an `onClickListener` on the custom icon/button and you can do whatever you want with it then.

Answer (score 0):

The Menu is inflated in the onCreateOptionsMenu method, and uses a menu XML in the menu folder (default) to retrieve items. If you would like to perform an action on the keycode menu, you can use the following

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
        switch(keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
    }
```

if you have no use for menu items, you can also go ahead and get rid of the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected methods, as well as the menu XML, that is up to you though